# Check against list field in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have field with value as list. For example

```
_id = 1
tags = ["IT", "mobile", "OS"]

_id = 2
tags = ["Mac", "fast", "laptop"]

_id = 3
tags = ["IT", "android", "OS"]
```

I got a list to check against the tag field.

```
sample = ["OS", "opera", "mobile"]
```

So docs with `id 1` and `id 3` should match when i query the tags using sample set.(Cause `id 1` contains `"OS"` and `"mobile"`  and `id 3` conatins `"OS"`.)

How can i do this on elastic search ?

Comment: Did you solve it successfully ? Or any help needed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below boolean query with the "should" [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "tags": "OS" }},
        { "match": { "tags": "opera" }},
        { "match": { "tags": "mobile" }} 
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe an important note for further queries: If you plan to search and Object that contains ALL 3 values (but not 2 or just 1 tag) you should definitely read about [nested objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html) in Elasticsearch first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
GET /_search

    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            { 
              "terms": 
                { 
                  "tags": ["OS", "opera","mobile"]
                }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```